# How to i might use Angular 2 & YII2?

Tags: angular, yii2

In what reason for this question?
I'd like use *Angular2* routes at my Frontend side, addition to that i want to use *YII2* view, from backend side.

I thought about *AJAX* page loading by *Angular2* for *YII2* pages...
hmm... That's idea. But should I do it?

In fact what i needed, from *Angular2* just REST API, and some modules on that one.
At last... How i must make *Angular2* and *YII2* urls combine.

For example *Angular2* path:

> somedomain.com/#/vehicles/child/12

YII2 path:

> somedomain.com/vehicles/child?id=12

I have much VIEWS at *YII2* and not so much at *Anuglar2*, because i want combine them

How it will do not difficult produce?

Comment: why combining them? why not just a separate SPA frontend app that communicates with the Yii2 REST api within a service consuming it using http like it is done in [this article](https://offering.solutions/articles/angular/consuming-a-rest-api-with-angular-http-service-in-typescript/) ?

Comment: Can someone please edit this question to make it easier to read?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to install the Angular2 project in `/angular2` for example and exclude that path in the `.htaccess` file responsible for the Yii2 rewrites.

You can use rule like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/angular2/$`

Answer (score 0):

Check out YII2 URL manager, you can change how url looks like 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html